# In MongoDB, can you index a field to find objects that don't have a value in an array?

Tags: mongodb

I know that [Multikeys](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys) allow you to efficient find objects that have an array as a field, where a particular value is present in that array.

For example, you could store an object:

```
{
  "ar":["book","cat"]
}
```

And then, provided the "ar" field is indexed, you could say:

```
db.blah.find({"ar":"cat"})
```

And it will efficiently find the above object.

However, would something like this work:

```
db.blah.find({"ar":{$not : "cat"}})
```

Here I'd like to find all objects where the "ar" array does **not** contain a "cat".  Would this query work, and if it works, would it be efficient?  (ie. would it use the index on the "ar" field?)

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at this [MongoDB server issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1017), the answer is "it can use the index".

However, when using the `$not` operator, it's often not very efficient to use the index. If `'cat'` appears in 2% of the entries, then you still have to read through 98% of the data. At that point, you might as well just read the whole data set one entry at a time.

Comment: The idea is that "cat" would appear in all but a few of the entries.  That being said, the issue you link to only refers to a simple "not equals" on a field, it doesn't refer to a "does not contain" on an array.

Answer (score 1):

The $not operator is not used in the way you imply, it is a meta operator that is used to negate the check of another operator only.  I think you actually mean to use $ne:

```
db.blah.find({ "ar" : { $ne : "cat"}})
```

If you do that and you have an index on "ar" then because it is a negative match you are going to have to scan just about all of the documents in the index to check each one - that is actually less efficient than scanning the table alone, because you have to do the index load/scan, then pull all the data to return results too.

If this is important enough and frequent enough to want to avoid this occurring, then why not add a simple field that is true/false (or 0/1 in my example) to test for the existence of the "cat" field.  Here, I am adding such a field to an existing data set, I would suggest adding it on creation or modification to add "cat" in the future though - avoiding batch operations is usually a good idea:

```
db.blah.update({ "ar" : "cat"}, { $set : {"cat_test" : 1 } }, true, true)
db.blah.update({ "ar" : {$ne : "cat"}}, { $set : {"cat_test" : 0 } }, true, true)
db.blah.ensureIndex({ "cat_test" : 1 })
```

Now you can just run something like:

```
db.blah.find({ "cat_test" : 0 })
```

That will make efficient use of an index.  Whether or not this is worth it will depend on your data usage and your model, of course